# I'm trying to retrieve a value in span classes in an online XML-file in android.Help me with Sample Codes

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I want to get value from the URL. please do some help or provide some helpful link where i can get the solution. Please help thanks in advance.

```
try {
     URL url = new URL("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
     URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

     NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Cube");

     Element element = (Element) nodes.item(0);
     NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("Cube");
     Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
     Toast.makeText(this, "USD " + line.getTextContent().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout how to use:

```
XmlPullParser
```

in Android developer's website [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)